# Is every Lie group the automorphism group of a riemannian manifold?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Given a finite-dimensional Lie Group $G$, is there always a Riemannian manifold $M$, such that $G$ is the group of isometries of $M$?

Comment: Hello mon cher, related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87070/can-every-lie-group-be-realized-as-the-full-isometry-group-of-a-riemannian-mani

Comment: Note that MO answer applies only to compact groups, so the question raised here (and the original MO question!) are both open in general as far as I can tell.

Comment: @studiosus  My impression is that the second reference in Igor Rivin's answer on MO applies to arbitrary connected Lie groups.  In any case, this question is essentially a duplicate of the MO question, so it makes sense for this to be closed.

Comment: @JimBelk: If you read Rivin's answer carefully, you will see that it applies to Kobayashi metric, which is not (in general) Riemannian (it is only Finsler and is typically non-smooth). Furthermore, it applies only to connected Lie groups. As far as closing, I am not sure what is the exact policy on MO-MSE duplication.

Comment: @studiosus Ah, good point about the Kobayashi metric.  I've opened a bounty on the MO question to see if we can get a more complete answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Torsten Hĕrculĕ Cärlemän points out, this question has been answered on MathOverflow:

[Can every Lie group be realized as the full isometry group of a Riemannian manifold?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87070/can-every-lie-group-be-realized-as-the-full-isometry-group-of-a-riemannian-mani)

Comment: Note that MO answer applies only to compact groups, so the question raised here (and the original MO question!) are both open in general as far as I can tell. I do not understand why this "answer" was accepted (unless Dominik is not interested in noncompact Lie groups).

Comment: @studiosus: I think that the second answer to the MO question gives a (albeit rather sketchy) argument that every Lie group (compact or not) arises in that way.

Comment: @Dominik: This is not the case. I guess, you are not realizing that Kobayashi metric is almost never Riemannian. One can attempt to promote it to a Riemannian metric (say, replace the Finsler balls with the least volume ellipsoids or something analogous, and then smooth out the resulting metric somehow), but then it becomes very unclear why the isometry group remains the same. Furthermore, the result about complex manifolds applies only to connected groups.